# Workflow Foundation (WF) -- Why does setting a DependencyProperty to a COM object using SetValue() throw an ArgumentException?

Tags: .net-3.5, com, workflow-foundation, com-interop

Assume that I have a .NET Workflow Foundation (WF) `SequenceActivity` class with the following "output" property:

```
public IWorkspace Workspace { get; private set; }
//     ^^^^^^^^^^
//     important: this is a COM interface type!

public static DependencyProperty WorkspaceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Workspace",
        typeof(IWorkspace),
        typeof(FoobarActivity));   // <-- this activity class
```

---

This activity executes some code that sets both of the above like this:

```
this.Workspace = ...;   // exact code not relevant; property set to a COM object
SetValue(WorkspaceProperty, this.Workspace);
```

---

The last line (which makes the call to `SetValue`) results in an `ArgumentException` for the second parameter (having the value of `this.Workspace`):

> *Type `[…].IWorkspace` of dependency property `Workspace` does not match the value's type `System.__ComObject`.*
>                                             (translated from German, the English exception text might differ slightly)

As soon as I register the dependency property with `typeof(object)` instead of `typeof(IWorkspace)` as the second parameter, the code executes just fine. However, that would result in the possibility to assign just about any value to the dependency property, and I do not want that.

**It seems to me that WF dependency properties don't work for COM interop objects.
Does anyone have a solution to this?**

Comment: Btw., moving on to .NET 4.0 and using `dynamic` (which *might* solve the problem) is currently not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a first answer to my own question, I found this work-around to work:

**If the COM object is wrapped in a .NET object, Workflow Foundation will be able to deal with it.**

---

**(1)** First define a generic helper class:

```
public class Wrapped<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }

    public Wrapped(T init)
    {
        Value = init;
    }
}
```

---

**(2)** Then, change the above activity property definitions to:

```
public Wrapped<IWorkspace> Workspace { get; private set; }
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//     this is now a .NET class type wrapping a COM object instance.

public static DependencyProperty WorkspaceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Workspace",
        typeof(Wrapped<IWorkspace>),
        typeof(FoobarActivity));
```

---

**(3)** Finally, the assignment to the `Workspace` property now becomes:

```
this.Workspace = new Wrapped<IWorkspace>(...);
```

---

While this works just fine, it's still only a workaround.
**If someone has a more elegant solution, I'd love to hear about it.**